# Mahout - Naive Bayes

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I tried deploying 20- news group example with mahout, it seems working fine. Out of curiosity I would like to dig deep into the model statistics,

for example: bayes-model directory contains the following sub directories,

trainer-tfIdf  trainer-thetaNormalizer  trainer-weights

which contains part-0000 files. I would like to read the contents of the file for better understanding, cat command doesnt seems to work, it prints some garbage.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The 'part-00000' files are created by Hadoop, and are in Hadoop's `SequenceFile` format, containing values specific to Mahout. You can't open them as text files, no. You can find the utility class `SequenceFileDumper` in Mahout that will try to output the content as text to stdout.

As to what those values are to begin with, they're intermediate results of the multi-stage Hadoop-based computation performed by Mahout. You can read the code to get a better sense of what these are. The "tfidf" directory for example contains intermediate calculations related to term frequency.

Answer (score 3):

You can read part-0000 files using hadoop's filesystem -text option. Just get into the hadoop directory and type the following

```
`bin/hadoop dfs -text /Path-to-part-file/part-m-00000`
```

part-m-00000 will be printed to STDOUT.

If it gives you an error, you might need to add the HADOOP_CLASSPATH variable to your path. For example, if after running it gives you

> text: java.io.IOException: WritableName can't load class: org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable

then add the corresponding class to the HADOOP_CLASSPATH variable

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/src/mahout/trunk/math/target/mahout-math-0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

That worked for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to read part-00000 (sequence files) you need to use the "seqdumper" utility. Here's an example I used for my experiments:

> MAHOUT_HOME$: bin/mahout seqdumper -s
>   ~/clustering/experiments-v1/t14/tfidf-vectors/part-r-00000
>   -o ~/vectors-v2-1010

-s is the sequence file you want to convert to plain text

-o is the output file